# Regarding importing .ppm file format in netlogo, as done in cruise model

Tags: gis, netlogo

I selected a small map area from Google Earth and saved it as jpg file. Later i converted it into .ppm file format. Then I tried to import this .ppm file in NetLogo. But a run-time error occurs "This non standard character is not allowed (line number 5, character 1)" with file-read in the following code line

```
ask patches [
  set pcolor rgb (file-read / 256) (file-read / 256) (file-read / 256)
]
```

Below is the jpg which I converted to .ppm (portable pix map) text graphics format. [image]

The code I am doing is

```
 globals [
     mapname
 ]
 to startup ; slow, do just once
     init-map
 end

 to init-map
       set mapname "sangamarea";   set mapname "cruise"
       create-dat mapname
  end

 to create-dat [mapfile]
       print "..creating patches, I'll print 'done' when completed"
       import-ppm mapfile
       export-dat mapfile
       print "..done!"
  end

  to import-ppm [ppmfile]
        let x 0 let y 0 let scale 0 ;locals [x y scale]
         set ppmfile (word ppmfile ".ppm")
         file-close-all
         file-open ppmfile
         set x 1 set y file-read-line
         while [first file-read-line = "#"] [set x x + 1]
            file-close
            file-open ppmfile
            repeat x [set x file-read-line]
              set x file-read
              set y file-read
              set scale 1 + file-read
              if x != random-xcor and y != random-ycor [print "Oops: need to fix screen-size to match ppm file"]
             ask patches [set pcolor rgb (file-read / 256) (file-read / 256) (file-read / 256)]
            file-close 
        cleanup-map
  end

  to cleanup-map
         ask patches with [(floor pcolor) mod 10 = 9] [set pcolor 9.9]
         ask patches with [pcolor != 9.9] [set pcolor round pcolor]
         ask patches with [pcolor > 120] [set pcolor pcolor - 110]
  end

  to export-dat [datfile]
           set datfile word datfile ".dat"
           file-close-all
           if file-exists? datfile [file-delete datfile]
           file-open datfile
           ask patches [file-write floor pcolor if pxcor = max-pxcor [file-print ""]] ;screen-edge-x
          file-close
  end
```

I don't understand why the error is, whether my jpeg image is large size or May be .ppm file contains non numerical value. I am following the steps of car cruise model. For any help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We wrote the cruising model in 2004 before Netlogo was able to import images directly. We used the .ppm image format as it was in a loadable ASCII format.

Soon after, Netlogo added commands like `import-pcolors`, `import-pcolors-rgb`, `import-drawing` and the bitmap extension.

I recommend skipping the PPM load process and load your .jpg directly with `import-pcolors-rgb`. Further, to avoid compression artifacts that can affect your colors, consider using .png format.